# Converting Boolean functions to polynomials

Tags: boolean-computation

We can generate a Boolean function of $n$ variables (take $n=4$ as an example) as follows:

```
f = BooleanFunction[10, 4]
```

I want to express $f$ as a polynomial. This is almost achieved by converting the function to the "ANF" form. All that's left is to get *Mathematica* to replace the `And` operator by multiplication, and the `Xor` operator by addition. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Why not make the replacements directly? `expr /. {And -> Times, Xor -> Plus}`

Comment: @J.M. Close, but not enough for the general case `BooleanConvert[BooleanFunction[1, 4], "ANF"] /. {And -> Times, 
  Xor -> Plus}`

Comment: @Dr. bel, the `Not[]` is indeed a problem. OP did not give instructions on how it should be dealt with, however. BTW: no need for `BooleanConvert[]`: `BooleanFunction[1, 4, "ANF"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
bf[n_, m_] := BooleanFunction[n, m, "DNF"] /. {Not[a_] :> (a - 1)^2, And -> Times,
              Xor -> Plus, Or -> Plus} /. (Plus[a__] &) :> (Unitize[Plus[a]] &)

bf[10, 4]
(* (#1 - 1)^2 (#2 - 1)^2 #4 & *)
```

Checking:

```
bt[n_, m_] := Boole /@ BooleanTable[BooleanFunction[n, m]]

And @@ ((bt[#, 6] == bf[#, 6] @@@ Tuples[{1, 0}, 6]) & /@ Range[2^6])

( * True *)
```

Comment: It works, somehow. But not always return a proper polynomial. Try for example `bf[300, 10]`. The `Unitize[ ]` stays in there. Looking for a better option.